# JAVA - Automatic post on Facebook wall without app

Tags: java, html, ajax, http, facebook

I am trying to simulate a user behavior on Facebook through the org apache HttpClient and currently I am able to login into the user page (obviously having the username and password).

Now I would like to post a simple message on the wall through the common http call that the user makes when he/she clicks on the "submit" button.

I decoded some parts of the ajax call done to the "updatestatus.php" page but I wasn't able to publish into the stream.

My question is:
Does anyone already successfully posted on the wall using this kind of process?

Just another note: I don't want to register an app for some special reasons.

Thank you
C

Comment: So, you want your application to publish to Facebook wall without registering it?

Comment: If there are any legitimate reasons as to why you cannot register an app, please describe it. As for my guess, Facebook would have some mechanism to prevent people from doing exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is to register an app and use Facebook's APIs. What are the "special reasons" you can't do that?